# How to add PrimaryButtonCommad to ContentDialog in WindowsPhone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am showing a TextBox in ContentDialog and when i press ok i want to get the value of textbox and call a method. I can't find anything related to it. This is my code.

```
 var box = new ContentDialog()
                    {
                            Title = "File Name",                                
                            Content = fileName,
                            PrimaryButtonText = "Ok",
                            PrimaryButtonCommand = ,
                            SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel"
                    };

                    await box.ShowAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*PrimaryButtonCommand*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.primarybuttoncommand.aspx) is a property and you can put there a object which has an *ICommand* interface. If you had added a *BasicPage* to your project, then VS should also add *Common* folder with some templates, there you will find a *RelayCommand* class, which you can use for your purpose, a sample can look like this:

```cs
private async void secondBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var box = new ContentDialog()
            {
                Title = "File Name",
                Content = fileName,
                PrimaryButtonText = "Ok",
                PrimaryButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(myAction),
                SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel"
            };
    await box.ShowAsync();
}

private async void myAction()
{
    await (new MessageDialog("User clicked ok")).ShowAsync();
}
```